# conflicting lifetimes in rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

The code is to let the score_handler handle the scores from some school in method operate(), the handle() just does some computing instead of keeping the reference of the self.school:

```
trait Class{
    fn student_count(&self, )->usize;
    fn student_score(&self, i: usize) ->u64;
}

trait School<'a>{
    fn class_count(&self)->usize;
    fn class(&'a self, i:usize)->&'a dyn Class;
}

trait ScoreHandler<'a> {
    fn handle(&'a mut self, school: &'a dyn School<'a>);
}

struct Coordinator<'a>{
    some_value: u64,
    school: &'a dyn School<'a>,
    score_handler: &'a mut dyn ScoreHandler<'a>
}

impl Coordinator<'_>{
    pub fn main(&mut self){
        self.operate();
        if self.some_value == 0 {
            println!("0");
        }
    }
    fn operate(&mut self){
        self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
    }
}
```

I got errors:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  -> mytest/main/src/main.rs:29:28
   |
29 |         self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
   |                            ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 28:5...
  -> mytest/main/src/main.rs:28:5
   |
28 | /     fn operate(&mut self){
29 | |         self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
30 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  -> mytest/main/src/main.rs:29:9
   |
29 |         self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 21:18...
  --> mytest/main/src/main.rs:21:18
   |
21 | impl Coordinator<'_>{
   |                  ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> mytest/main/src/main.rs:29:28
   |
29 |         self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
   |                            ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut dyn ScoreHandler<'_>`
              found `&mut dyn ScoreHandler<'_>`

...
```

so I changed the <'_> to <'a>, like this:

```
trait Class{
    fn student_count(&self, )->usize;
    fn student_score(&self, i: usize) ->u64;
}

trait School<'a>{
    fn class_count(&self)->usize;
    fn class(&'a self, i:usize)->&'a dyn Class;
}

trait ScoreHandler<'a> {
    fn handle(&'a mut self, school: &'a dyn School<'a>);
}

struct Coordinator<'a>{
    some_value: u64,
    school: &'a dyn School<'a>,
    score_handler: &'a mut dyn ScoreHandler<'a>
}

impl<'a> Coordinator<'a>{
    pub fn main(&'a mut self){
        self.operate();
        if self.some_value == 0 {
            println!("0");
        }
    }
    fn operate(&'a mut self){
        self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
    }
}
```

and I got errors:

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `self.some_value` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> mytest/main/src/main.rs:24:12
   |
21 | impl<'a> Coordinator<'a>{
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
22 |     pub fn main(&'a mut self){
23 |         self.operate();
   |         --------------
   |         |
   |         borrow of `*self` occurs here
   |         argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
24 |         if self.some_value == 0 {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `*self`

error[E0503]: cannot use `self.some_value` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> mytest/main/src/main.rs:24:12
   |
21 | impl<'a> Coordinator<'a>{
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
22 |     pub fn main(&'a mut self){
23 |         self.operate();
   |         --------------
   |         |
   |         borrow of `*self` occurs here
   |         argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
24 |         if self.some_value == 0 {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `*self`
...
```

I wonder if someone could help me with a good solution for this, thanks!

Comment: If you remove all the <'a> except that of `Coordinator<'a>` [it compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a98f4a04cfa6124f913653a345ad354e). Would that work for you?

Comment: @rodrigo, it works, thanks! but I would  check why I used the lifetime for school etc, since this is a simplified demo which is quite different from my original code, where I used the lifetime to fix another issue. Be back soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I strongly suggest you reconsider your type architecture. Why are `Class` and `School` *traits*? Do your different classes have different implementation details, as in, one uses a `Vec` internally, and the other a `HashMap`?

As rodrigo already pointed out in the comments, you can simply remove a few `'a`s, and it compiles. Reason being, that with your code you literally say, that the mutable self borrow by `Coordinator::operate()` will last as long as that by `Coordinator::main()`, but then you reborrow it there.

That then looks like this:

```rust
trait Class {
    fn student_count(&self) -> usize;
    fn student_score(&self, i: usize) -> u64;
}

trait School<'a> {
    fn class_count(&self) -> usize;
    fn class(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a dyn Class;
}

trait ScoreHandler<'a> {
    fn handle(&mut self, school: &'a dyn School<'a>);
}
struct Coordinator<'a> {
    some_value: u64,
    school: &'a dyn School<'a>,
    score_handler: &'a mut dyn ScoreHandler<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Coordinator<'a> {
    pub fn main(&mut self) {
        self.operate();
        if self.some_value == 0 {
            println!("0");
        }
    }
    fn operate(&mut self) {
        self.score_handler.handle(self.school);
    }
}
```

Of course, you also have to define some actual structs to implement these traits, I'll give an example:

```rust
struct ClassA {
    student_scores: Vec<u64>,
}

impl Class for ClassA {
    fn student_count(&self) -> usize {
        self.student_scores.len()
    }
    fn student_score(&self, i: usize) -> u64 {
        self.student_scores[i]
    }
}

struct SchoolA<'a> {
    classes: Vec<&'a dyn Class>,
}

impl<'a> School<'a> for SchoolA<'a> {
    fn class_count(&self) -> usize {
        self.classes.len()
    }
    fn class(&'a self, i: usize) -> &'a dyn Class {
        self.classes[i]
    }
}

struct ScoreHandlerA {
    some_internal_state: u64,
}

impl<'a> ScoreHandler<'a> for ScoreHandlerA {
    fn handle(&mut self, school: &'a dyn School<'a>) {
        for i in 0..school.class_count() {
            println!("Handling a class in a school");
        }
    }
}
```

And then again, your main might look something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let classes = vec![ClassA {
        student_scores: vec![13, 14, 15],
    }];
    let school = SchoolA {
        classes: classes.iter().map(|c| c as &dyn Class).collect(),
    };
    let mut coordinator = Coordinator {
        some_value: 13,
        school: &school,
        score_handler: &mut ScoreHandlerA {
            some_internal_state: 0,
        },
    };

    coordinator.main();
}
```

Comment: thanks! This is a simplified demo, while my original code is more complicated. Actually in my original code, the class is corresponding  to some complicated cache which is variable but the interface is simple and fixed , school is a cache list while actuall it is a double end queue, so I just want to hide the implementation. Anyway, the question is helping me understand better about the lifetime, since I think I am still quite unenlightened about it.

Comment: You can hide the implementation just fine with a struct, simply only make the public parts `pub`. Well, whatever, you'll know what you're doing, just a friendly pointer by me. Lifetimes are really not that complex, you might be enlightened if you try to write a toy program with all lifetimes being explicit. Very verbose, but it might help you.

Comment: the reason I make them as interfaces is try to de-couple the implementations. ok, I am going to check my code. If there was no doubt, I would like to take your answer accepted. thanks a lot for your very detailed code.

Comment: Feel free to update your question in case another problem comes up :)